# Crashin Angular project docker container

Tags: angular, docker, node-modules

I have docker container for angular project, using node 18;
Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm update

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4200"]
```

problem is when I run sudo `docker-copmose build`, its good but then i try `sudo docker-compose up` it has an errors :

> auralab-angular | Node packages may not be installed. Try installing
> with 'npm install'. auralab-angular | Error: Could not find the
> '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
> auralab-angular exited with code 1

I am using google-cloud unbutu machine, but i dont know error reason.
docker-compose.yaml:

```
angular:
    image: auralab-angular:latest
    container_name: auralab-angular
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    command: ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4200"]
    depends_on:
      - django
```

structure is :

```
project:
|___client:
|_______Dockerfile
|_______other files;
|___docker-compose.yaml
```

Comment: `ng serve` starts a dev server. It's not optimized and secured against attackers. Don't use it in a Docker container.

Comment: The `volumes:` block in your Compose file hides everything in your image, including its `node_modules` directory, and you should delete it.  You also don't need to override the `command:` or `container_name:`.